# Java Mysql You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql

No me deja cambiar el valor predeterminado de un campo en la base de datos que tengo que usar para hacer un trabajo incluso siendo root, y encima me da un error de que un campo no tiene valor por defecto, ¿que hago?

```
num_emp1.setText("" + rs.getDouble("num_emp"));

GuardaEmp = Double.parseDouble(num_emp1.getText());

private void AceptarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    try
    {
        sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
        tablaEmp.insertar(sqlDate, GuardaJefe, 
        nombre1.getText(),GuardaDpto,GuardaEmp,
        GuardaSalario,tarea1.getText());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Cuando he añadido por fin un valor por defecto me sale el error de:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

y si intento borrarlo desde java me sale esto otro:

> Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

No se que hacer.

Comment: Pon el código que estás utilizando y el error que te sale.

Comment: Deberías hacer el [tour] y [edit] tu pregunta para añadir la información relevante de tu problema

Comment: mira a ver si el problema está en si hay un punto o coma como separador de los decimales

Answer (score 0):

Vale lo he solucionado, pero ahora me sale nullPointerException y no se por que.
y me lo da en la siguiente linea:

```
rs.updateDouble("num_emp", num_emp);
```

a parte de en el boton de insertar, he comprobado en la base de datos los . o las , y todo esta bien y en su sitio no se que pasa

Comment: Sin código es difícil poder ayudarte. Este error del NullPointerException puede ser porque tu base de datos te está regresando un nulo y se lo estás asignando a un primitivo. Los primitivos no soportan nulos y lanza la excepción. ¿Qué tipo de dato es num_emp?

Comment: es un double, y devolver me lo devuelve en el select pero a parte de eso no me deja insertarlo me da el error el codigo que he pasado es donde me da el error y no se ni por que

Comment: Pues ese es el error double es primitivo y no admite nulos(lanza la NullPointerException). Ocupa Double(con la mayuscula inicial) es tipo objeto y debe permitirte usar nulos

Comment: no puedo cambiar el tipo de dato que quiero actualizar, y tampoco puedo cambiarlo en la base, pero de todas formas no tendria por que, porque es que tengo que coger un double ademas es la primary key y no hay ningun valor nulo en la base asi que no se por que me devuelve un nulo, ademas en la base tampoco aparece un .0 despues del numero aun siendo un double